# Travis CI fails restoring a netcore 2.1 project

Tags: .net-core, travis-ci, asp.net-core-2.0

See the travis log here:
https://pastebin.com/KQYkYxvC

errors seem to relate to:

```
[39;49m[31m/home/travis/build/frostebite/UKSFWebsite.Backend/UKSFWebsite.api/UKSFWebsite.api.csproj : error NU1102: Unable to find package Microsoft.NETCore.App with version (>= 2.1.0) [/home/travis/build/frostebite/UKSFWebsite.Backend/UKSFWebsite.Backend.sln]
```

This does build and work with the preview netcore sdk and visual studio locally.

Answer (score 1):

Because .NET Core 2.1 is in preview, I think you have to point the Travis config to the specific preview SDK version. For example, if you are targeting `trusty`, below is a sample of *part* of a `travis.yml` that should work.

```
dist: trusty
language: csharp
before_install:
- curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg
- sudo mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg
- sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-ubuntu-trusty-prod
  trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1.300-preview1-008174
```

You can modify above for whatever your target platform is by using the instructions on the [.NET Core 2.1 preview download page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/sdk-2.1.300-preview1).

I just [tested this in one of my projects with success](https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/commit/bd3849abe8712dd9336b5b292c0fd2a27306cb01).